# Journey Builder Question on entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a simple journey setup where the entry source is a filter Data extension. 
That filter DE is setup in automation studio to gather the records that quality to enter.

Upon entering, users will receive email 1 and I have a 3 day wait period after that which checks to see if they opened or did not open email 1. If they did open, these users will exist. The users that did not open will receive their email #2 message.

The journey setting is set to not allow re-entry.

The journey will run from May 5th till June 1st (for email 1). Email #2 needs to stop sending to those un-opened users on June 4th (this will be the last day they receive a message). If I stop the latest version after it runs on June 1st, will the current users in the stream continue on until June 4th? I want to ensure if anyone falls into being a non-opener receives their last message on June 4th.

Or would I have to pause my automation studio program that filters out my data extension to ensure no else new enters after June 1st and have my journey run until the 4th and stop it there?

Thank you in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop the journey on June 1st, the journey status will be stopped then all the contacts which is present in june 1st will be stopped. They wont enter into the next criteria where you are checking whether the contact opened email or not.

You can find more info on journey status in here - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_journey_statuses.htm&type=5

- So, you can either pass the journey on June 1st so that there will be
  no new entry into the journey.
- Or you can use schedule the journey from automation and schedule the
  automation from May 5th end at June 1st. In this case you dont have
  to manually pause it.

Let me know if this helps.